# PHP/SQL - Search two terms to return data stored in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, datetime

The concept:

- User enters gender, birthday (y-m-d) and other info, this is stored
  in db.
- There is a query (`query.php`) page, dedicated to specific search terms, the first form is to search a specific gender from a select option (male, female) and enter a age.
- This form is POSTED to `queryRun.php` with the result displayed (if any).

Now I've attempted this several times but I'm struggling with changing the birthday into a age without entering the birthday manually.

The code below works, but as you can see the `$dob` is manually entered (how would i change this to the data entered into database in previous step).

```
<?php
  //birth date in yyyy-mm-dd format
 $dob = "1993-10-03";

//explode the date to get year , month and day
 $dob = explode("-", $dob);


 //get age from date or birthdate
    $current_month = date("m");
    $current_day = date("j");
    $current_year = date("Y");
    $age = $current_year - $dob[0]; 
    if($current_month<$dob[1] || ($current_month==$dob[1] && $current_day<$dob[2])) $age--; 
    echo "Age is ". $age;   

?>
```

Once the calculation for the age is sorted, i then need to search the database for the entered criteria, i have this, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
if($_POST['sRetrieveBirthday'] && $_POST['sRetrieveGender']) 
    $queryRetrieve = mysql_query( "SELECT * TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sRetrieveBirthday, CURDATE()) 
    AS sBirthday FROM staffData WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sRetrieveBirthday, CURDATE()) > '40'");

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($queryRetrieve, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
        {       
echo '    <td>'.$info["sBirthday"].'';
```

this is the error i receive,

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/-/www/-/asQueriesRun.php on line 31 SELECT failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sRetrieveBirthday, CURDATE()) AS sBirthday FROM staffData ' at line 1
```

Any ideas guys? I've been struggling for days now and without getting this core concept working i cant move to other search queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Comma after `SELECT *`

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sRetrieveBirthday, CURDATE()) 
AS sBirthday 
FROM staffData 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sRetrieveBirthday, CURDATE()) > '40');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the * from your SELECT it should work.